Arrows labelled "Leaderboards" on "See reduced ads" privilege wiki are pointing at the wrong thing
When looking at reduced ads privilege docs page, I got very confused looking at the illustration.
It appears that the red arrows that are labelled "Leaderboard" are actually not pointing at the leaderboard ads, but at the sidebar ads, see screenshot and read the text which is confusing, probably wrong.

I checked this somewhat related question, but it's not a duplicate. The new image is different: Is the "Privilege: reduce ads" page outdated?
